# Swift Int array every 3 elements sum

Tags: swift, algorithm

For example, we have an array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

```
let index1 = 0
let index2 = 0
let index3 = 1+2+3
let index4 = 2+3+4
let index5 = 3+4+5
....

let result = [index1, index2, index3, index4, ...]
```

Comment: for you example array, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12], what must be the result??

Comment: note that Swift collection indices are zero based

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate your collection indices, add a guard to return zero in case it is less than 2 otherwise return the sum of the actual value + the last two values:

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

let result = numbers.indices.map { index -> Int in
    guard index > 1 else { return 0 }
    return numbers[index-2...index].reduce(0,+)
}

result  // [0, 0, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]
```

or simply

```
let result = numbers.indices.map { $0 < 2 ? 0 : numbers[$0-2...$0].reduce(0,+) }
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

let result = [0, 0];
for (var i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`index${i + 1} = ${arr[i - 2]}+${arr[i - 1]}+${arr[i]}`);

    result.push(arr[i - 2] + arr[i - 1] + arr[i]);
};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

First initialize the result list

```
let result = [0,0]
```

Then a for loop to traverse the list and every loop you want to add the 3 elements together and append to result.

```
for i in 0...len(ary)-2:
  result.append(ary[i][i+1][i+2])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
let array: [Int] = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ]
let filterSize = 3

var movingSum = 0
var outputArray: [Int] = []

for (index, element) in array.enumerated() {

    movingSum += element

    if index >= filterSize - 1 {

        if index >= filterSize {
            movingSum -= array[index - filterSize]
        }

        outputArray.append(movingSum)

    }

}

print(outputArray)
```

output:

```
[6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33]
```